# How would write ansible script to find if directory is mounted or not?

Tags: directory, ansible, mount

I need to check if a directory is mounted or not.  I have checked on doc.ansible for help but they only have create or delete. 
I am using visual code for ansible and vm for directory file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html#setup-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) returns a list of mounted filesystems "ansible_mounts". It is possible to test it

```
ansible remote-host -m setup
```